# White space on right of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: A picture is worth a thousand words]

How do I get rid of that undesired white border on the right of the page?

The website basically dynamically resizes images on a grid, here's a video: https://vine.co/v/h2wtnw6K3H0

CSS:

```
body {

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

grid {

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.gridImage {

    vertical-align: bottom;

    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
function resize() {

    console.log($(window).width());

    var newBody = "";

    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {

        newBody += '<img class="gridImage" src="Images/image2.jpg" width="' + $(window).width() / Math.floor(($(window).width() / 100)) + 'px" height="' + $(window).width() / Math.floor(($(window).width() / 100)) + 'px">';
    }

    document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = newBody;
}
```

If my margins are zero, why is this showing up? Anything I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: @Hardy Haha, it's not a scrollbar.

Comment: :) looks like scrollbar.. are you sure it's not? Try same page in firefox.

Comment: html { margin:0; }  
I know it doesn't make much sense but see if it works

Comment: The problem is that the pictures get wrapped, you will have to use absolute position.

Comment: @wumm I need them to be wrapped, that's how I create the grid.

Comment: wait!! Your javascript, you have used Math.floor there so if you calculate 1 pixel less while floor() it will most probably leave 10pixels at right??

Comment: This works good at me http://jsfiddle.net/m7wM3/0/. As Nikihil already pointed out you maybe should remove this floor.

Comment: @wumm The Math.floor() I'm using is for figuring out how many images I should have for each row based on the screen size, because 10 images each row on a phone may get too small. However, once I get an exact number of images I want to use, I use that to scale each image so they're exact. For example, if the screen was 305 pixels, my website would decide to show three pictures for each row, with each picture being 305 / 3 pixels wide.

Comment: Probably you should look at a responsive CSS grid like in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ridcully has covered what the problem is, but here’s a solution.

First you would need to calculate the desired width of each image. This is simply your current equation wrapped in `Math.ceil()`.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width() // A slight performance improvement, plus cleaner code
var maxImageWidth = <your value here>

var unroundedImageWidth = windowWidth / Math.floor(windowWidth / maxImageWidth)
var   roundedImageWidth = Math.ceil(unroundedImageWidth)
```

Unless your images fit perfectly, this will make each row slightly wider than the window, causing the final image on each line to wrap to the next. To prevent this, you need to set the gridContainer’s width to that of each row.

```
$('.gridContainer').width(windowWidth * roundedImageWidth / unroundedImageWidth)
```

Everything should look good, except for one thing: the horizontal scrollbar. This is easily fixed, however. Add this to your CSS:

```
.gridContainer {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This will hide both the scrollbar and the final few pixels on each line. Perfect! Well, not quite.

The problem with this method is that one image per row takes the hit (loses pixels) for all of the others. If you have small images and a lot of images per row, you could end up losing a significant portion of your final column.

To avoid this, you can round your image widths upwards and distribute the overflow amongst all images in the row. This is a little more complicated than the previous method, but it does give a better result.

There are three more numbers you need to calculate.

```
var imagesPerRow = windowWidth / unroundedImageWidth
var numOfRows = Math.ceil($('.gridContainer img').length / imagesPerRow)
var spillage = windowWidth / roundedImageWidth - windowWidth // Pixels we have to lose
```

Now it’s just a matter of distributing the spillage.

```
var i = 0 // Loop counter

while (spillage !== 0) {
     // Set the width of all images in column i to the width of that column - 1
     $('.gridContainer img:nth-child(' + imagesPerRow + 'n-' + (i+1) + ')')
         .width($('.gridContainer img:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')').width() - 1)

    spillage--
    i++
}
```

There should no longer be more than a single pixel difference between the widths of the images.

Comment: This helped so much, I can award you the bounty tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of rounding errors. What you do is fill the `grid` with 100 scaled images, depending on the browser to wrap to a new line when the image doesn't fit in the current row any more.

Now imagine a width of 305 pixels. Your formula gives an image width of 100 for that, so you get 3 images in a row and the next one wraps to the next row, leaving 5 pixels blank at the right border.

Comment: It shouldn't give 100 pixels. The Math.floor() I'm using is for figuring out how many images I should have for each row based on the screen size, because 10 images on a phone may get too small. However, once I get an exact number of images I want to use, I use that to scale each image so they're exact.

Comment: For example, if the screen was 305 pixels, my website would decide to show three pictures for each row, with each picture being 305 / 3 pixels wide.

Comment: 305 / 3 is 101.666666666. As you need an integer value for width, you'd end up with 101 for width leaving 2 pixels blank (305 - 3*101), or if you round up you'd get a width of 102 and that would already wrap after the second image.

Comment: New to web development, more of an iOS developer :) Didn't know widths had to be integers. Argh, that sucks. Okay, thanks.

Comment: So if the container is centered, it will look intentional

Answer (score 0):

i think you should also add `padding:0;` to body its missing from your code.

Try it and even better just make a jsfiddle then it would be easier to check for everyone.